# Tailwind margin animation

Tags: tailwind-css

I have this div overlay effect. The display effect is working, but the margin is not.

```
<div className='relative aspect-[4/3] bg-black group'>
    <div className='transform duration-1000  mr-0 group-hover:mr-10  
        hidden group-hover:block absolute bg-white top-0 mt-[40px] right-0 p-10'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The margin hover is working (though I would recommend you transition transform properties instead of margin) but your issue is that you have `hidden group-hover:block` which is attempting to transition display which is not a transitionable property.

Instead you can transition opacity <strike>`hidden group-hover:block`</strike> -> `opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-100` as shown in this example https://play.tailwindcss.com/FmsPzOn6P5

And to use translate instead of margin transition <strike>`mr-0 group-hover:mr-10`</strike> -> `group-hover:-translate-x-10` see this example https://play.tailwindcss.com/5WcZvKUFRO

Transitioning transform instead of margin is recommended for performance reasons see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Performance/CSS#animating_on_the_gpu